# É possível fazer cópia de arquivos sem utilizar buffer com stream?

Tags: java, arquivo, memória, buffer

Na minha aplicação tenho uma classe que periodicamente efetuam um *backup* de um arquivo, consideravelmente pequeno(menos de 1MB), mas estou fazendo uns testes e após ler [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1690724/5524514), me parece que foi sugerido que se pode fazer cópias sem ter que utilizar *buffer*. Com o código abaixo, eu estou utilizando *buffer* de 4kb, e o resultado até que é bem satisfatório.

Segue o código que estou usando:

```
private static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst); 
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

É possível efetuar essa cópia sem utilizar *buffer*? Remover o *buffer* realmente otimiza a cópia de arquivos?

Comment: Você quer usar algo pronto ou quer fazer o algoritmo na mão?

Comment: @bigown bom, inicialmente gostaria de entender, mesmo que seja de forma resumida, o funcionamento. Claro que um exemplo não seria de todo ruim, mesmo que não tenha muito a ver com o que eu exemplifiquei.

Comment: É que a pergunta não está clara quanto a isso, se for algo pronto, já está respondido, você poderia colocar o que já fez no chat. Se quer saber como fazer manualmente, a pergunta não fala sobre isto.

Comment: @bigown o que eu queria saber é se é possivel, utilizando inputStream e outputStream, fazer a cópia sem ter que usar buffer, aquele código lá que mostrei é usando filechannel.

Comment: É possível, como você já leu no SO, basicamente tem que acessar o DMA, eu não sei como fazer isto em Java. Mas acho que neste caso não pode usar *stream*. Acho estranho usar um *stream* , se não for usar memória.

Comment: @bigown minha dúvida é  essa:  se era possivel, e se há beneficio de desempenho nisso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na minha concepção, depois de alguma avaliação, se entendi a pergunta, **não é possível**.

A cópia sem o uso de *buffer* é possível usando [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access), assim nem passa pela memória. Esta operação precisa ser atômica, ou seja, não pode ser uma leitura e depois uma escrita, tem que ser algo simultâneo (mesmo), tem que ser algo feito pelo hardware sob comando do sistema operacional. Não sei se o Java dá acesso ao DMA, e se isso se confirmar, teria que fazer algo em C chamando a API específica e expor ao Java, provavelmente com [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Mas como *streams*, pelo menos os disponíveis na API do Java,  devem ser ou de leitura ou de escrita, é necessário um *buffer*. Com essa API não é possível, precisaria usar uma API que não exige um processo intermediário.

Acredito que só é possível fazer com [`FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html). Mesmo esse eu não posso afirmar que usa o DMA. A documentação não deixa claro nada sobre isto e talvez seja detalhe de implementação.

Outras opções dão indícios que usam *buffer*.

Remover o *buffer* certamente dá um grande ganho de performance já que não precisa passar pela memória, só não espere milagres, afinal a memória é rápida e o armazenamento de secundário (ainda) é lento.